# 2013 - Update Item - Path and Name - Fails

Tags: document-library, updatelistitems, move

I have 2 libraries both published from an identical InfoPath 2013 form. I am trying to move items from `Library A` to `Library B` with a simple workflow:

`Update Item in Current Item`

With:

`Field` set to `Path and Name`

and

`Value` set to `...mysite.../Library B/[%Current Item:Name%]`

The error information I get is:

> RequestorId: 1975a6b8-d75c-b5a5-0000-000000000000. Details: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the workflow instance. Exception details: System.ApplicationException: HTTP 500 {"Transfer-Encoding":["chunked"],"X-SharePointHealthScore":["0"],"SPClientServiceRequestDuration":["73"],"SPRequestGuid":["1975a6b8-d75c-b5a5-831e-6c1d65951804"],"request-id":["1975a6b8-d75c-b5a5-831e-6c1d65951804"],"X-FRAME-OPTIONS":["SAMEORIGIN"],"X-Content-Type-Options":["nosniff"],"X-MS-InvokeApp":["1; RequireReadOnly"],"MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices":["15.0.0.4649"],"Cache-Control":["max-age=0, private"],"Date":["Mon, 06 Jun 2016 14:21:23 GMT"],"X-AspNet-Version":["4.0.30319"],"X-Powered-By":["ASP.NET"]} at Microsoft.Activities.Hosting.Runtime.Subroutine.SubroutineChild.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

I have seen some similar posts on here with (like so many others) either no answers or no accepted answers. Some suggestions include not requiring document check out in the versioning settings. My library already does not require document check out.

Answer (score 1):

When you use “Update List Item” and update the “Path and Name” field with the folder name where the document should be moved in.

The destination folder must not have different permissions by which the current user cannot actually access it, If this occurs than you will get above error which is mentioned in your question.

For solve such issue, you will need to add an impersonation step in the beginning of the workflow.

Please refer below mentioned link for more information.

[How to move documents using workflow in SharePoint 2013 and Office 365](https://plumsail.com/blog/2014/06/how-to-move-documents-using-workflow-in-sharepoint-2013-and-office-365/)

**Updated**

Someone managed to resolve the problem, and as suspected it was the Path and Name syntax in SPD 2010

In the Create New List Item dialog under Path and Name, you can use the following:

```
/site_or_subsite/library_name/xxx.docx

/site_or_subsite/library_name/xxx[%Current Item:ID%].docx
```

Hope this helps... as it is [mentioned here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9e0eae53-566e-4b6e-84c5-27c7b2c51749/update-item-in-list-path-and-name-the-workflow-could-not-update-the-item?forum=sharepointcustomizationprevious).

Comment: Hi @Hardik, both the person who created the item and the person triggering the workflow (in this case me - admin - manually triggering a workflow to test this) have `Full Control` in both libraries. So I doubt it's a `Permissions` issue?

Comment: Than you can use **Copy Item** & than after **Delete Item** methods to avoid such problems. These are really easy steps mentioned here...http://www.documentmanagementworkflowinfo.com/sample-sharepoint-workflows/sharepoint-designer-workflow-move-document-one-library-next.htm

Comment: Did you manage to Move document?

Comment: Hi Hardik, Copy and Delete works just fine but my understanding is that there are some pretty fundamental differences between this action and the move action. Also, I want to change the name of the file based on some rule during the move process. If I copy I can't do this and, furthermore, I can't trigger a new workflow in the destination library because the 'On Creation'  routine is not triggered with copy. So this isn't an acceptable substitute for me. I need the change path and name to work and don't get why it doesn't here.

Comment: I understand changing a document's metadata, but changing the actual filename, which is the user-facing metadata that makes a document unique, seems a bit off

Comment: Please check updated answer if you can find something for you from it.

Comment: Hardik, there are 3 reasons why a workflow on this document type can end. At the end of the workflow the document is moved to a historic documents library with the reason for finishing the workflow appended to the filename.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40830/discussion-between-hardik-and-trojanian).

Comment: Hardik... in your answer did you mean for it to say xxx[%Current Item :ID%].docx       or should it have just been the current item id field (not pluncked in the middle of that file name?